# JSP - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [11] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

Tags: jpa, jsp

ALGUÉM SABE DIZER O QUE EU ESTOU FAZENDO DE ERRADO?

```
public List<Usuario> obterusuario(String user){

    Consultar consulta = new Consultar ();
    EntityManager obconsulta = consulta.getEntityManager();

    System.out.println("passou"+user);

    String query = "SELECT U FROM CADASTRO_USUARIO U WHERE U.USR_CODIGO=:user";

    TypedQuery<Usuario> tq = obconsulta.createQuery(query,Usuario.class);
    tq.setParameter("user", user);

    return tq.getResultList( );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No banco de dados, o campo **ID** está como outro formato que não é **String**, (*varchar* ou *longtext*).
Seu *user* está sendo passado como **String**.

A solução seria, ou você troca o argumento do método para *Integer/int*, ou você faz um *parse* com a classe **Integer**:

```
Integer realUser;
try {
  realUser = Integer.parseInt(user);
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  //o valor passado não é um número
  realUser = null;
}
```

Por fim, na instrução `tq.setParameter` você vai passar a variável `realUser` ao invés da `user`.

```
tq.setParameter("user", realUser);
```

Espero ter ajudado.